# How do I keep fixed-size thread pool fixed size despite Await.result?

Tags: multithreading, scala, async-await, threadpool, executorservice

How do I prevent `ExecutionContext`'s internal thread pool size from growing in the following use-case?

**1. Execution context**

```
  val par = 64    // thread pool size
  implicit override def executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(
    java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(par),
    t => {
      System.err.println("Exception in child thread: " + t.getMessage)
      t.printStackTrace()
      throw t
    })
```

**2. A lot of `Future`s (but less than `2*par`)**

```
val futureList = ArrayBuffer[Future[Int]]()
...
futureList += Future { ... }
```

**3. Await**

```
futureList.foreach(Await.result(_, Duration.Inf))
futureList.clear()
```

**4. Operating system thread limit exceeded**

```
Exception in thread "pool-1896-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want this fixed thread pool size to really stay fixed! How do I do that?

The number of `Future`s is less than `2*par` but this function (2-3) is executed `16` times (sequentially), so the total number of `Future`s is larger. But the implicit `executionContext` (as defined in 1) is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: `Await.result` blocks the current thread of execution. So just DO NOT use that. This is an XY-Problem here. Just ask about what you actually want to achieve instead of asking about the use of `Await.result`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh what's wrong with blocking? Blocking the current thread until all the ``Future``s it has created are done, is exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't think you're exceeding the thread pool size you've set - and regardless, `Await` won't create new threads. Try increasing your application's memory.

Comment: `Await.result` should not be the cause of your actual problem. If you are sure that you need something like `Await` then use it, but avoid it whenever it is not explicitly required.

Comment: The important question is - do you create a new thread pool whenever the function is called ? what about clearing the old thread pools ?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I just tried this example and did not get any `OutOfMemoryError`. I specified `val par = 1000` and looked into thread pool stats (`getMaximumPoolSize`, `getLargestPoolSize`) which was `1000`. It looks like logic in the future is consuming a lot of RAM and therefore you get `out of memory`. Try replacing logic in future with smth simple like `Random.nextInt(100)` and see if this issue reproduces.

Comment: JVM thread creation problem is a complicated case depending on may factors including the nature of your jvm and os - 32 bit or 64 bit, jvm heap space. To read more - https://dzone.com/articles/outofmemoryerror-unable-create

Comment: This creates 980 threads, I can see their IDs.